# Nextjs static build on Android 4.4 - Set is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, polyfills, next.js, babel-polyfill

I have static build of nextjs app running in react-native webview.

It runs on all devices except those with Android 4.4 version.

Console says that Set is not defined which should means that there is something wrong with polyfill.

I added .babelrc setting with

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "env",
        {
            "modules": false,
            "debug": true,
            "useBuiltIns": true,
            "targets": {
                "browsers": [
                    "android >= 4.4",
                    "ios_saf > 9",
                    "and_chr >= 56"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "next/babel"
]
```

}

and my console even says that

```
 es6.set {"android":"4.4","ios":"9.3"}
```

is set, but it still doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Did you find answer on your question? I have exact the same problem, it doesn't work on old android webview, but the same time works in the chrome even on 4.4

Comment: Babel-polyfill didn't solve this problem. This helped https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/features/. Just include it to your _document.js file.